# Accelerations in a Free Body Diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

Let's say there are multiple systems in place, with pulleys as so on. I need to know how do I find the entire acceleration for the system, so as to apply the convention properly.
For example,

[image]

In  this image if you notice the highlighted image, the acceleration is supposed to be towards the right for the plank and it should be down for M hanging.

For M hanging, it should be T = Ma + Mg because a is downward, then why is it that in FBD-1, Ma is show upward and the equation is given as T + Ma = Mg.

And even for the triangular block the acceleration is supposed to be to the right but it's not so.

I believe I'm making a conceptual error, and I need to rectify it immediately.

> The question states, " Find the mass M of the hanging block in figure which will prevent the smaller block from slipping over the triangular block. All the surfaces are FRICTIONLESS and the strings are pulleys are light.

Comment: See, what matters is that physically the acceleration a is in same direction for both masses. Whether a is actually downward or upward doesn't matter, as long as the equations are kept consistent. Let's say the answer is $x$ downward. As a is taken upward in the equations, the solution will come out to be $-x$. Voila!!

Comment: Silly me. Forgot that a convention is meant to be a convention. Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

On block $M$ gravitational force ($Mg$) is acting downwards, tension ($T$) upwards and net acceleration is downwards

According to Newton's 2nd law
$F\text{(net external force)}=M\times \text{acceleration}$

Here $F$ and a are vectors means acceleration will be in direction of net force

As we know the acceleration is downwards the net resultant force will be downwards.

The vector sum of $Mg$ and $T$ is $Mg-T$ (downwards) and is equal to $M \times$ (acceleration i.e. a)
Hence $$Mg-T=Ma$$

**Alternative**
Let us consider direction of acceleration -ve
We will write equation as

$-Mg+T=-Ma$ (net external force=mass×acceleration)

Or we consider direction of acceleration          as +ve
We will write equation as

$+Mg-T=+Ma$ (net external force=mass×acceleration)